# C++ reading contents from file into a map

Tags: c++

I have a file that I want to read into a map.

```
file.txt
temperature 55
water_level 2
rain        10
........
```

While I am aware that I could use the C function 'sscanf' to parse the data. I would prefer to do this in C++ (I am only getting used to the language) and read it into a map (with the first column as the keys and 2nd as the values).

I have attempted it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const char *fileName="/home/bsxcto/Wedeman_NucPosSimulator/test/params.txt";
    ifstream paramFile;
    paramFile.open(fileName);
    string line;
    string key;
    double value;
    map <string, int> params; #### errors
    while ( paramFile.good() ){
        getline(paramFile, line);
        istringstream ss(line);
        ss >> key >> value; # set the variables  
        params[key] = value; # input them into the map 
    }
inFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

However it's on the initialisation of the map structure that I get a bunch of errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - ‘value’ cannot appear in a constant-
     expression
    - ‘key’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
    - template argument 2 is invalid
    - template argument 1 is invalid
    - template argument 4 is invalid
    - template argument 3 is invalid
    - invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

I have also tried 'map' and 'map', but they do not work either.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you actually have `#` in your source like "`#### errors`"?

Comment: @drescherjm They are different libraries, although the C one isn't being used there.

Comment: And what is `inFile`? Basically, you have made no effort to fix this yourself before posting here. Voting to close for typographic errors.

Comment: Looks like you're using a weird compiler: I've never seen an error message formatted like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not using # as comment (because you have to use `//`).

I got a different error than you:

```
prog.cpp:24:1: error: ‘inFile’ was not declared in this scope
```

After fixing that, I got no compilation errors.

By the way, this code:

```
map <string, int> params; // errors
while ( paramFile.good() ){
    getline(paramFile, line);
    istringstream ss(line);
    ss >> key >> value; // set the variables  
    params[key] = value; // input them into the map 
}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
map <string, int> params; // errors
while ( paramFile >> key >> value ) {
    params[key] = value; // input them into the map 
}
```

In this snippet, `( paramFile >> key >> value )` evaluates as true if `paramFile` is good after trying to read the key and the value.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct kv_pair : public std::pair<std::string, std::string> {
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, kv_pair& p) {
        return in >> std::get<0>(p) >> std::get<1>(p);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ifstream paramFile{"/home/bsxcto/Wedeman_NucPosSimulator/test/params.txt"};
    std::map<std::string, std::string> params{std::istream_iterator<kv_pair>{paramFile},
                                              std::istream_iterator<kv_pair>{}};
}
```

Comment: as usually, the best answer is not the most upvoted...

Answer (score 1):

Template `map` declaration is correct, problem is in comments. `#` is not used as one line comments in c++ use `//`. `inFile.close();` change to `paramFile.close();`.